# Why is giving me this error :TypeError: cannot pickle '_io.TextIOWrapper' object?

Tags: python, selenium, multiprocessing, pool

I am trying to use multiprocessing and the idea is to get the links from the result of the Bing Search, but changing  one of the configurations (cep configuration) using selenium. I have all the cep in a list (filecep) and I wanto to write all of the results on a csv file.
This is my getUrlCleans function :

```
def getUrlCleans(search):


driver = webdriver.Firefox()

f = open('out/'+str(date.today())+'.csv','w')
f.write('url,cep')
f.write('\n')

url_cleans=[] 

pool=mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
pool.starmap(getUrlbyCEP,[(cep,driver,search,f) for cep in filecep])
pool.close()
f.close()
```

This is my getUrlbyCEP function :

```
def getUrlbyCEP(cep,driver,search,f):

driver.get('https://www.bing.com/account/general?ru=https%3a%2f%2fwww.bing.com%2f%3fFORM%3dZ9FD1&FORM=O2HV65#location')
                
    
cepInput = driver.find_element_by_id('geoname')
cepInput.clear()
cepInput.send_keys(cep)
time.sleep(0.5)
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")


saveButon=driver.find_element_by_id('sv_btn')
saveButon.click()




try:
    driver.find_element_by_id('geoname')        
    # continue
except:
    pass

searchInput=driver.find_element_by_id('sb_form_q')
searchInput.send_keys(search)

driver.find_element_by_id('sb_form_q').send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
time.sleep(0.5)

url_cleans=[]

for i in range(2):
    
    url_cleans=getLinks(driver,url_cleans)
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@title="Próxima página"]').click()
    url_cleans=getLinks(driver,url_cleans)
    for u in url_cleans:
        f.write(u+','+cep)
        f.write('\n')
```

Finally I call

```
getUrlCleans('sulamerica')
```

ang It gave me the error.... and I do not know why?

Comment: `multiprocessing` basically pickles objects that processes need to communicate between with. Does `threading` work for you?

Comment: I have never used threading, good suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @PanwenWang I follow your suggestion and it worked!

Answer (score 3):

So instead of using multiprocessing I used threads and it worked. This is what I change, instead of:

```
pool=mp.Pool(mp.cpu_count())
results = pool.starmap(getUrlbyCEP,[(cep,driver,search,f) for cep in filecep])
```

from multiprocecessing library (mp), I used this:

```
from multiprocessing.dummy import Pool as ThreadPool    
pool = ThreadPool(4)
results = pool.map(f_partial, filecep)
```

Comment: A ThreadPool has completely different performance implications than a multiprocessing Pool. In Python, threading only works well on IO bound processes due to the Global Interpreter Lock (GIL). Although this error may not occur with the ThreadPool, it's important do be aware of the fundamental differences between Python threads and processes.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem without using multiprocessing.  I switched to using dill https://pypi.org/project/dill/ and that works. Dont know why and dont really care.  Just want it to work.